# Connecting to Google Fit Consent Screen Denying one of multi permissions will not connect - cordova ionic application

Tags: cordova-plugins, healthkit, google-fit

My app is trying to connect to Google Fit. The user is prompted to pick a Google Account and once picked, the "Consent Screen" shows up requiring users to accept or deny each permission. There are separate screens for each permission. Once the user has gone through each permission pop up to accept or deny, a main screen appears that shows a list of all the permissions with check marks next to the ones that the user had allowed. If the user denies one or more of the permissions, it usually closes the pop up, shows a spinner, and then restarts the consent screen pop ups to force the user to go through each permission pop up and then continues to the main pop up of the whole list of permissions.

Comment: What is your question? See https://developers.google.com/fit/android/authorization. Quote: `Google prompts the user to grant your app the required scopes. If the user consents, your app can access fitness data of the requested types.` If you don't grant, then there is no access.

Comment: Expected result is to show the data for permission accepted. but if you deny some of the options. permission popup is triggering again and consent is coming again and again. this is happening when user deny the some of the option in permission popup.